# 'IMyInterface' does not contain a definition for 'MediaExists' - Makes no sense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have been refactoring some code to split some core features into a second code library. As part of this I've split one of my interfaces in two. Here's how it used to look...

```
namespace Ministry.Ministryweb.Repositories
{
    public interface IMinistrywebPublishedContentRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the media item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id of the item.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IPublishedContent MediaItem(int id);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the umbraco helper.
        /// </summary>
        UmbracoHelper Umbraco { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if a piece of media exists.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaId">The media id.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool MediaExists(int? mediaId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the URL for some media content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaId">The media id.</param>
        /// <returns>A nicely formed Url.</returns>
        string MediaUrl(int? mediaId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the content URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nodeId">The node id.</param>
        /// <returns>A nicely formed Url.</returns>
        string ContentUrl(int nodeId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the content at a specific node.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The node id.</param>
        /// <returns>Dynamic content.</returns>
        dynamic Content(int? id);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the blog roll.
        /// </summary>
        IBlogRoll BlogRoll { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the root ancestor.
        /// </summary>
        IPublishedContent RootAncestor { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the consultancy URL.
        /// </summary>
        string ConsultancyUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the development URL.
        /// </summary>
        string DevelopmentUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the team management URL.
        /// </summary>
        string TeamManagementUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the root ancestor.
        /// </summary>
        string RootAncestorName { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an article with the specified ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Article Article(int id);
    }
}
```

And here's how it looks now I've split the interface in two. The first interface is defined in the Ministry,Ministryweb class library...

```
namespace Ministry.Ministryweb.Repositories
{
    public interface IMinistrywebPublishedContentRepository : IPublishedContentRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the blog roll.
        /// </summary>
        IBlogRoll BlogRoll { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the root ancestor.
        /// </summary>
        IPublishedContent RootAncestor { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the consultancy URL.
        /// </summary>
        string ConsultancyUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the development URL.
        /// </summary>
        string DevelopmentUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the team management URL.
        /// </summary>
        string TeamManagementUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the root ancestor.
        /// </summary>
        string RootAncestorName { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an article with the specified ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Article Article(int id);
    }
}
```

This inherits now from a parent interface in Umbraco.Pylon, my new library...

```
namespace Umbraco.Pylon
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An interface for accessing published content.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IPublishedContentRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the media item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id of the item.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IPublishedContent MediaItem(int id);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the umbraco helper.
        /// </summary>
        UmbracoHelper Umbraco { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if a piece of media exists.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaId">The media id.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool MediaExists(int? mediaId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the URL for some media content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaId">The media id.</param>
        /// <returns>A nicely formed Url.</returns>
        string MediaUrl(int? mediaId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the content URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nodeId">The node id.</param>
        /// <returns>A nicely formed Url.</returns>
        string ContentUrl(int nodeId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the content at a specific node.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The node id.</param>
        /// <returns>Dynamic content.</returns>
        dynamic Content(int? id);
    }
}
```

My main web project is a third project called Ministryweb with references to both libraries. Ministry.Ministryweb also has a reference to Umbraco.Pylon. With this setup everything compile fine, but when I load this view...

```
@inherits MinistrywebViewPage
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = DynamicModel.Name + " - " + Ministryweb.Content.RootAncestorName;
}
@section PageTitle
{
    @DynamicModel.PrimaryHeader
}
<section id="primary">
    @if (Ministryweb.Content.MediaExists(DynamicModel.MainImage))
    {
        <div class="serviceImage">
            <img src="@Ministryweb.Content.MediaUrl(DynamicModel.MainImage)" alt="@DynamicModel.Name" />
        </div>
    }
    @DynamicModel.IntroText
    @foreach (var service in DynamicModel.Children)
    {
        <h3><a href="@service.NiceUrl()">@service.Name</a></h3>
        <p>@service.Summary</p>
        <span class="linkButton"><a href="@service.NiceUrl()">@service.TagLine</a></span>
        <br />
    }
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
<section id="asideContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_SocialSidebar")
    @Html.Partial("_LogosSidebar")
</section>
<section id="articles">
    @Html.Partial("_LatestArticleForAll")
</section>
```

I am presented with the following error...

**'Ministry.Ministryweb.Repositories.IMinistrywebPublishedContentRepository' does not contain a definition for 'MediaExists'**

This makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever.

Originally there was no direct reference from the Ministryweb web project to Umbraco.Pylon, so I included that explicitly, following a suggestion on another post but that made no difference.

The maddening thing is that if I duplicate the code from the IPublishedContentRepository interface in the IMinistrywbPublishedContentRepository interface then everything works fine, ReSharper just moans at me (and rightly so). Any thoughts on what might be causing this would be most welcome as it's halted my refactoring job in it's tracks.

Comment: Have you tried a full clean and rebuild?

Comment: I did try a rebuild but I think I'll have to go through the paranoid clean routine again now I've changed the references and see if that helps.

Comment: I'd also make sure you don't have a duplicate definition of `IMinistrywebPublishedContentRepository` left over somewhere that's conflicting with your new version.

Comment: Good shout - I'll double check. I renamed the interface when refactoring though so that's unlikely. I have a couple of theories to check out this morning and I'll post up more info after.

Comment: No joy on either of those two options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - This is more of a workaround than a final answer so I won't mark it as such, I just thought this may be relevant to anyone looking this up in the future.

This issue only happens when trying to access the property of the interface through the view. I use the same interface throughout my codebase as a parameter passed in to various objects and it works completely fine. This is a bit weird (and I'd still like to know why really).

The view accesses the interface through this class, which is simply present to expose content elements to views...

```
namespace Ministry.Ministryweb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Elements for the site.
    /// </summary>
    public class Ministryweb
    {
        private static IContainer container;

        #region | Construction |

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Ministryweb" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="umbracoHelper">The umbraco helper instance.</param>
        public Ministryweb(UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper)
        {
            Content = new MinistrywebPublishedContentRepository(umbracoHelper);
        }

        #endregion

        public IMinistrywebPublishedContentRepository Content { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

The view itself inherits from this base class to get an instance of the class...

```
/// <summary>
/// An abstract base class for Ministryweb views.
/// </summary>
public abstract class MinistrywebViewPage : UmbracoTemplatePage
{
    private Ministryweb ministryweb;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the model in a dynamic form.
    /// </summary>
    public dynamic DynamicModel { get { return CurrentPage; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point for helper functions defined at root site level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The ministryweb helper object.
    /// </value>
    public Ministryweb Ministryweb
    {
        get
        {
            ministryweb = ministryweb ?? new Ministryweb(Umbraco);
            return ministryweb;
        }
    }
}
```

It occurred to me, as this is simply an accessor for the Views there was absolutely no reason to define the Content property as an interface. If instead I do this...

```
namespace Ministry.Ministryweb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Elements for the site.
    /// </summary>
    public class Ministryweb
    {
        private static IContainer container;

        #region | Construction |

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Ministryweb" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="umbracoHelper">The umbraco helper instance.</param>
        public Ministryweb(UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper)
        {
            Content = new MinistrywebPublishedContentRepository(umbracoHelper);
        }

        #endregion

        public MinistrywebPublishedContentRepository Content { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

... everything works just fine.

I hope this helps people.